# Drupal 8 Bootstrap: How do I add the ing-responsive class to images?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drupal-8

I'm creating a Bootstrap sub theme for Drupal 8. Previously I've used drupal 7 (with some difficulty) but I want to move on to drupal 8 for a new site and I'm in a bit over my shoulders. I'm having trouble understanding twig and the documentation I've found.
For instance I want images to be responsive by default. I've activated the responsive images in the settings that bootstrap offers. The comment says:

> Images in Bootstrap 3 can be made responsive-friendly via the addition
>   of the .img-responsive class. This applies max-width: 100%; and
>   height: auto; to the image so that it scales nicely to the parent
>   element.

But how do I add the class to images? Do I edit the twig-files or can it be done in a simpler way? The "templates/system/image.html.twig" already contains the code:

```
{% set classes = [
  theme.settings.image_shape ? theme.settings.image_shape,
  theme.settings.image_responsive ? 'img-responsive',
] %}
<img{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }} />
```

To me this looks like it should already be applying the class I want if the responsive image option is checked?

Any guidance would be much appreciated!

Comment: Ok, it seems like the code above adds the img-responsive class to images inserted as an image field, but not as inline images. This is good enough for me, as I don't think I'll need inline images to be responsive.